# Advantages of using multiple entities in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, swift, entity

I'm using Core Data in my app and I have many "categories" of data. Some are smaller and some are bigger, and I thought to divide some of the categories to different entities.
So I wanted to ask, if there are any advantages or disadvanteges to using multiple entities even if not mandatory, and if I should also create an entity for smaller "categories" of data? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the rule that I use:

If incorporating data into the entity itself with attributes does not result in *excessively* repetitive data, I would **prefer to add attributes** rather than new entities.

This is a subtle tradeoff in which you have to consider

- Performance
- Complexity of the data model
- Code legibility.

If you consider these factors carefully with the guidance above, I am sure you can make good decisions on when to create new entities rather than using attributes.

For example, if you have an entity like `Story` that has attributes like `title`, `text`, `date`, etc. and would like to add a category, in most cases it would make sense to create a to-one or even to-many relationship to a `Category` entity rather than using a string attribute. Presumably, there will be hundreds of stories and dozens of categories, and the flexibility to have more than one category is a definite advantage.

On the other hand, if you have an entity `Story` which is always one of not more than three types, i.e. "report", "analysis" or "opinion", you would be better off with an `enum` type of attribute rather than a relationship to a new entity.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not overly sure what you mean by categories but, obviously the bigger the entity the more memory your app will take up when you load the entities into your NSManagedObjectContext. However there's no real point splitting entities up into two when you're just going to load them both anyway.

In terms of performance Core Data docs mention that even 10,000 objects is a pretty small database. Just be careful with BLOBs, dont load data you dont need into memory and release data when you can using NSManagedObjectContext's reset method.